# Why is my formatter returning a nil NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, date

The following code will set `date` to nil.

```
NSString *dateString = @"2014-04-27T04:20:07.000-04:00";
NSString *UTC_FORMAT = @"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:UTC_FORMAT];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

*What am I doing wrong?*

I've tried many other different variations for `UTC_FORMAT`, but counldn't seem to get it. I'm also a little bit confused as to when and where the single quotes go. After playing with this for a while, I'm assuming it can goes around characters that shouldn't be interpreted by the formatter, but that's a separate thing.

**Related Links That Couldn't Help Me:**

1. [Apple Docs: Data Formatting Guid](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)
2. [SO: Why is NSDateFormatter returning nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599376/why-is-nsdateformatter-returning-nil?rq=1)

**Formats That I've Tried:**

```
NSString *UTC_FORMAT = @"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'";
NSString *UTC_FORMAT = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-Z";
```

Comment: Are all those apostrophes really neccessarry in the format string? That's probably the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: I've tried the same string without the apostrophes. The above `UTC_FORMAT` is taken directly from the Apple Docs.

Comment: Remove quote ('') from your `UTC_FORMAT` it would be `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-Z"` ?

Comment: @Bharat, I've tried that and it does not work.

Comment: If you need other formats: The Apple Docs don't actually describe any of the formatting. Somewhere hidden in their documents is a link to the www.unicode.org website that documents it in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date looks like a quite standard JSON date format in RFC3339 format. However, there are several possibilities how these dates can be formatted. In this case, your date string contains milliseconds. Your date format doesn't, so this cannot work. The following code will check for dates without fractional seconds first, then for dates with fractional seconds. Furthermore, you are looking for a literal character Z instead of a timezone.

The "X5" is documented at

http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

and converts time zones in quite a flexible way, including the colon in the middle. .SSSSSS will convert fractional parts of seconds up to microseconds. Should you be given nanoseconds change it to nine S characters.

And I forgot the locale information...

```
NSString *UTC_FORMAT = @"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssX5";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:UTC_FORMAT];
enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
gmtTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
[formatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[formatter setTimeZone:gmtTimeZone];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

if (date == nil)
{
    NSString *UTC_FORMAT2 = @"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSSSSSX5";
    NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter2 setDateFormat:UTC_FORMAT2];
    [formatter2 setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
    [formatter2 setTimeZone:gmtTimeZone];
    date = [formatter2 dateFromString:dateString];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid dependencies on the current locale, add :

```
NSString *dateString = @"2014-04-27T04:20:07.000-04:00";
NSString *UTC_FORMAT = @"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:UTC_FORMAT];
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
```